# Generic inverse function in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have an abstract method which takes and returns long value, like so:

```
public abstract long func(final long value);
```

The method will be implemented by whoever is subclassing this class, but the algorithm used will have the following limitations:

- input value cannot be zero
- the result must be greater than zero and lesser than input value
- the same input value must always produce the same result
- two different input values cannot produce the same result
- the algorithm must be revertible

Also, the algorithm will likely be fairly complex and it can change over time (as new versions of the software are written). I would like to spare the implementor from having to write the inverse function, especially considering that, due to complexity, it is a potential source of bugs. Assume speed is not a factor. So I want to create a method that would generate the inverse of the previous method. Not knowing the algorithm used, the only way I see is to repeatedly call the **func** method until I get the desired result. This is untested code, written off the top of my head:

```
public long inverseFunc(final long value) {
    // Assume I can make an educated guess about expected result
    long expectedResult = makeEducatedGuess();
    long prevResult = 0L;
    while (true) {
        long newResult = expectedResult - ((expectedResult - prevResult) / 2);
        long intermediateValue = func(newResult);
        if (intermediateValue == value)
            return newResult;
        prevResult = expectedResult;
        expectedResult = newResult;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to implement this function? In this case, I simply split the difference between latest and the previous result by two, but maybe there is a way to be smarter about it.

**EDIT:**

This is the algorithm that is simple and works fairly well. I first set the expected result to doubled value, which is the most common case in my scenario. You can set it to whatever suits your purpose.

```
public long inverseFunc(final long value) {
    long expectedResult = value * 2;
    while (true) {
        long intermediateValue = func(expectedResult);
        long diff = intermediateValue - value;
        if (diff == 0L)
            return expectedResult;
        expectedResult -= diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem doesn't make much sense. Without knowing what the method does, you can't make any educated guess. Nothing guarantees there is even an inverse method. what would be the inverse of the following method: `return 0L;`? And of this one: `return new Random().nextLong();`?

Comment: heh :) I would love to see reverse of random() function

Comment: Inverse how? Do you mean you want to get the input value to `func` given an output value? That is, say you call `func(5)` which yields `10`, is your goal to make a method `funcInverse(10)` which yields `5`? Of course if this is possible depends entirely on the implementation of `func`.

Comment: I would like to see the top of you head, it must have heaps of writing on it.

Comment: I omitted some details for simplicity. The func method is meant for a specific task and it will never return zero or random value. Algorithm used may vary, but it will always return the same result for the same input value.

Comment: @user2310289: This is not the site for grammar nazis, but the mistake you point out is duly corrected. ;-)

Comment: @NikšaBaldun If it maps one input to one output, then there must be an algorithm selection process in your method. Replicate that, and then call the inverse for the selected algorithm.

Comment: @NikšaBaldun Sorry I do not consider it a mistake at all.  Just me being an idiot.  Slow day.

Comment: You must have more knowledge on the function in order to do something better than iterating over all its domain and testing. If for example you know that the function is monotonous, then a binary search can become very useful.

Comment: Another case where you may have a good solution is when the function f(x) is derivable. This allows using the Newton-Raphson method for finding the roots of g(x)=f(x)-y, for a given y value. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: How much will the values sent into func differ? One solution would be to make a Map with keys that are the results func returns and values the input. Would probably take up shitloads of memory but hey, it will solve your problem :P

Comment: @Eyal Schneider: I have no knowledge of the algorithm used, other that the result value will always be lesser than the input value and greater than zero.

Comment: @NikšaBaldun: that means that two input values will lead to the same returned value, which means that the function doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: @JB Nizet: No, two different input values will not yield the same result. I see I made a mistake in trying to oversimplify my question. I will try to rewrite it.

Comment: In addition to being *invertible*, the function must be *strictly monotonic* for your iterative approximation to work. If you don't have that, the adjacent values won't be telling you anything about the placement of the value you are searching for.

Comment: @Funtik wouldn't the inverse of random() be predictable() ;)

Comment: @jwenting. Code that :)